# conditional probability of two dice when none lands on 6

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Two fair dice are rolled. What is the conditional probability that none lands on 6 given that the dice land on different numbers?

What if I calculate the conditional probability that at least one lands on 6 given that the dice land on different numbers then the conditional probability P(A|B), I get is 1/3. Now the required conditional probability (none lands on 6) will be 1-P(A|B)?
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; the answer is $\frac23$. What you calculated is $P(\neg A\mid B)$, and it is easy to show that $P(\neg A\mid B)+P(A\mid B)=1$.